# What happened to Will Salas' father?

Tags: plot-explanation, in-time

In the movie [*In Time*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1637688/), when Timekeeper Raymond Leon meets main character Will Salas for the first time, he teases him by talking about Will's father who was too young to know him when he died. He also implies he knows what really happened to him, but we never learn what. What happened to Will's father?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just watched this movie and recall Raymond Leon saying something to the affect that Will's father's crime was giving time away. At another point in the movie, Will tells Sylvia he believes his father was murdered. I pulled these quotes from http://www.moviequotesandmore.com/in-time-movie-quotes-1.html

> [talking on the phone]
>   **Raymond Leon:** Hello, Will. How much do you want?
>   **Will Salas:** A thousand years.
>   **Raymond Leon:** You'll never live to spend it.
>   **Will Salas:** Then distribute it to the Timelines in Dayton. Do it by sunrise tomorrow and she can go home.
>   **Raymond Leon:** Well, I'm afraid for you, Will. You keep talking like him, you're gonna die like him.
>   **Will Salas:** Hey, my father died in fight trying to take a man's time.
>   **Raymond Leon:** Oh, no. His crime wasn't taking time. He was doing something far more dangerous. Please don't make your father's mistake.

---

> **Sylvia Weis:** Where's your family?
>   **Will Salas:** My mother timed out.
>   **Sylvia Weis:** This is her dress?
>   **Will Salas:** Yeah.
>   **Sylvia Weis:** What about your father?
>   **Will Salas:** Died when I was a boy. He was a fighter, strong arm. He wasn't the strongest, but he knew how to win.
>   **Sylvia Weis:** How do you win?
>   **Will Salas:** I'll show you.   [he takes her arm]
>   **Will Salas:** What you do is you let them have the upper hand, and then he let his time go all the way down because he knew that when you
>   were down to your last seconds, and they think it's over, they start
>   watching your clock and forget to watch their own.
>   **Sylvia Weis:** He died in a fight?
>   **Will Salas:** I think he was killed for giving away what he won. He wasn't just giving them time, he was giving them hope.

Answer (score 4):

> In one instance, Salas says he can always fight for money, but his mother reprimands him, telling him not to be like his father.
>
> Leon also makes a reference to Salas' father. Salas looks confused, as
>   he thought his father died in a fight. (Source:[www.themoviespoiler.com](http://www.themoviespoiler.com/Spoilers/intime.html))

Both point indicated that Salas father's death is a mystery and only his wife and Leon know about it. It kept mystery in the film till end.

As per [intime.wikia.com](http://intime.wikia.com/wiki/Will_Salas)

> Wills parents are both timed out.

Answer (score 3):

There is a deleted scene where Leon explicitly states that his crime was giving away time and a flashback shows the timekeepers timing him out to "correct the unbalance"

(link may expire)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Leon is Wills father.  throughout the film will's father is a very mysterious figure and not much about him is known.  The things we do know are that he was once in the ghetto, and that he was known for giving away his own time.  So it can be assumed that Will's father is someone who does what thinks is best for the world in an unselfish manner.  I believe that is also what drove him to become a timekeeper.  This is just a theory let me know what you guys think!

Answer (score 1):

There is something between Fortis and Raymon Leon. I think they are brothers or atleast grew up as friends. I wonder if fortis had somrthing to do with wills dad.

Comment: IT does not answer OPs question.